# How to add margin in responsive site

Tags: css

In this website I have two blocks. I would like add margin-top on the second div just when this div move below to first one on medium devices.

My problem is miss the alignment on top on large devices.

I have use the fundation.css

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="medium-12 large-3 columns">
        bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 large-9 columns" >
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Large devices]

---

[image: medium devices]

Comment: can you share some of your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you're using the mobile first approach, it can be done only by using the media queries

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="medium-12 large-3 columns">
        bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 large-9 columns marginDiv" >
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>

@media screen and (min-width: 760px) {

     .marginDiv{ 
         margin-top: 10px;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write media queries for this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

     .row > div:nth-child(2){ 
         margin-top: 1em;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply margin in css using unit of percentage ***( % )*** lyk  below,

```
{ margin-top:2%;}
```